# Correct Way To Build Multiple Docker Versions In GitHub Actions?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, docker-registry

I have a GitHub Action that is almost like the one below. The action's purpose is to build a Dockerfile and push it to DockerHub.

```
name: DockerHub Run
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "master"
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 0 * * 0"

env:
  DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: MyUser
  OFFICIAL_TAG: MyUser/MyImage:latest
  MAIN_REPO_NAME: MyUser/MyImage
  DOCKERFILE_PATH: /

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push image to DockerHub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
          file: ${{ env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE }}/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.OFFICIAL_TAG }}
      - name: Update repo description
        uses: peter-evans/dockerhub-description@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          repository: ${{ env.MAIN_REPO_NAME }}
          readme-filepath: ./readme.md
```

And according to DockerHub, the architecture is listed
[image]

However, I have a question about this line:

```
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
```

Im not sure if listing the platforms here actually compiles to those platforms. Keep in mind that GitHub is using `ubuntu-latest` which is x86-x64 and I do not have a ARM64 device to test.

Am I setting up correctly to build to ARM devices?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. The [docs for build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) say that platforms can be either a list or a set of comma separated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tldr

> Im not sure if listing the platforms here actually compiles to those
> platforms.

It does (assuming your the commands defined in your Dockerfile are platform conscious)

> Am I setting up correctly to build to ARM devices?

Your config looks correct and should build for amd64 and arm64. You can test by adding a step after the push and checking the output:

```bash
# assuming your image is debian based
$ docker run \
  --platform linux/amd64 \
  --rm \
  --entrypoint='' \
  MyUser/MyImage:latest \
  /bin/bash -c 'dpkg --print-architecture'

#output should be
amd64

$ docker run \
  --platform linux/arm64 \
  --rm \
  --entrypoint='' \
  MyUser/MyImage:latest \
  /bin/bash -c 'dpkg --print-architecture'

#output should be
arm64
```

## long answer

It "works" because of the emulators for the qemu emulators for a bunch of different platforms (aka `docker/setup-qemu-action@v2`) and then using docker buildx for the [multi-platform images](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/)

The problem is that even though everything seems to build fine in CI this way, the artifacts never really get tested on their respective native platforms, so to answer your question 'Am I setting up correctly to build to ARM devices?' ... ‍♂️

I find it similar to python and its universal2 wheels, where the cross-compilations are built, but not really ever tested (all very python and macos specific but the conversations point out challenges running integration/e2e tests for these multi platform artifacts):

- https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/197
- https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/4133
- https://github.com/actions/python-versions/pull/114
- https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/547

This github/community discussion also provides a *little* more depth on the multiplatform builds as well
https://github.com/community/community/discussions/38728#discussioncomment-4106829